# why Python is required to install Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, installation

To install cassandra DB, python is required. Why is that so.? 
What role Python plays in cassandra during installation and after(Is it for Driver connections?, or for `cqlsh`? because I see some python related files in cqlshlib folder)?
Cassandra is also a DB like others mongodb or mysql, oracle(of course some these are not noSQL and not distributed).

Comment: I guess because it uses Python scripts?

Comment: Python is not a hard requirement. If you use a package manager, it will install python to meet cqlsh dependencies. If you want to install cassandra without installing python, just download the binary tar, untar somewhere (/opt ?) configure (/opt/cassandra/conf/...) and run cassandra. You won't be able to execute cqlsh from the node of course. You can still run cqlsh from another server/your laptop (with python installed) if needed.

Comment: @ChristopheSchmitz: Without cqlsh, how can we create table and run query commands.? Is there any other approach exist other than datastax GUI, or cqlsh

Comment: @dave you can use one of the Cassandra drivers and write some code. Python would be the easiest way to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the `cqlsh` [is written](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/bin/cqlsh.py) in Python...

Comment: Wow, that's one of the easiest +6's that I've ever seen!  LOL.

Comment: github linke that show some of the part is written in python https://github.com/apache/cassandra